# Why are projected variables in canonical correlation analysis uncorrelated?

Tags: support-vector-machine, dimensionality-reduction, correlation

Let $x\in R^d$ and  $y\in R^e$ be two vectors with covariance and cross-covariance matrices
$S_{xx}, S_{yy}, S_{xy}, S_{yx}$. The canonical correlation analysis is based on the  projection of $x$ onto a lower dimensional representation $a$ and $y$ onto a lower dimensional representation $b$ such that the correlation between transformed points is maximized:

$a=W^Tx, b=V^Ty$ where $W$ is a $d\times k$ matrix and $V$ is a $e\times k$ matrix and
$k$ is the first k maximum shared eigenvalues of the matrices $S_{xx}^{-1}S_{xy}S_{yy}^{-1}S_{yx}$ and $S_{yy}^{-1}S_{yx}S_{xx}^{-1}S_{xy}$.

Question: are $a$ and $b$ uncorrelated? If so, why?